# Conditional based on _.where

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

With

```
var a = _.where(list, {key: "value"});
if (a) console.log("exists");
```

the conditional doesn't seem to work, but if I change to `if (a != "")` it does. Since a = [] when not finding anything I'm using `if (a.length > 0)`, but just curious why it works with an empty string and then not with the original example. Isn't an empty string in JS a falsy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an empty string is a falsy value in JavaScript, but `where` method returns an array and an array is an object which is not a falsy value, even *empty* arrays are truthy.

```
[] != '' // false
!![] // true
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I just expanded on the question to reflect that, but I'm curious why != "" works?

Comment: Because an array of values is not equal to an empty string.

Comment: But in the case of != "" it works. I.e. a = [] = "". That's what I don't grasp. With empty arrays being truthy, the conditional shouldn't work in this case, right?

Comment: @eee3 What does "work" mean? What do you expect? `a != ""` returns `false` as an Array object is not equal to an empty string!

Comment: I expected `[] != ""` to return true and `[] == ""` to return false.

Comment: An empty array stringifies to `''` thus `[] == ''`